# Adding a route or default gateway to QNX

Tags: routes, gateway, qnx

We have a system running QNX that normally connects to two other hosts on a 10.10.X.0 network. We are installing two remote systems that need to be able to talk to those servers on our 56.x.y.z network.

We can type:

route -n add 56.x.y.0/24 56.a.b.1   (2nd addr is the gateway)

It shows up in the routing table (route -f) and all works fine. The problem is when the system is rebooted of course it goes away. We need to make it persistent by creating or adding that line to some file that runs at boot-up. Sounds simple enough - like autoexec.bat in DOS. Or we just need to add a default gateway somehow as in Windows.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You can run the route command with '-p' so the routes are persistent after boot. Check this article on it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx